# Adding Java derived Thread classes to Vector fails

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

I'm trying to create a simple array of some `Worker extends Thread` class.
I declared a `Vector<Worker>` then tried to `.add(...)` elements to it.
I keep getting compilation errors. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class Main
{
    class Worker extends Thread
    {
        private final int serial;
        Worker(int serial) { this.serial=serial; }
        public void run() { System.out.printf("Worker %d\n",this.serial); }
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        int i=0; Vector<Worker> workers;
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers.add(new Worker(i)); }
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers[i].start();         }
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers[i].join();          }
    }
}
```

Here is my compilation line:

```
$ javac -d . Main.java
```

And here are my errors:

```
Main.java:12: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers.add(new Worker(i)); }
                                         ^
Main.java:13: error: array required, but Vector<Main.Worker> found
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers[i].start();         }
                                    ^
Main.java:14: error: array required, but Vector<Main.Worker> found
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { workers[i].join();          }
                                    ^
```

Comment: First error comes from the fact, that non-static inner class need a reference to outer class. While inside of static method, there is no `this`. You could declare the inner class as `static` to solve this problem. The second error appears because you declare the variable as a Vector and then try to access it as a regular Array. Vector is not an Array. Use `workers.get(i)` instead. As an extra, `workers` isn't initialized and you will have to handle some exceptions.

Comment: @Amongalen 'Non-static inner' is a tautology.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne you can have both static and non-static inner classes, no?

Answer (score -1):

You're calling a non-static class from a static method. Two simple solutions are:

- Make Worker static
- Make Worker a separate class

Second, user Workers.get(i) instead of Workers[i].

And last, surround Join method with try & catch or add an exception to the signature.

Comment: He is *instantiating* an *inner class*from a static *context.*